Procedure with table_name as variable
How to create procedure witn table name as variable
I'd done procedure with column name as variable, it works but when I've tired create procedure I've got errors
PROCEDURE getTable(in tableName VARCHAR(25))
begin
SELECT * FROM tableName
end

This question is similar to: How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Please also include an example of how you're calling the procedure, assigning the variable and the exact error you receive in your attempt. "I've got errors" is not helpful to us to help you resolve the issue.
